# Python List comprehension (convert sentence to words)

Tags: python

I am new to python and have a simple doubt.

I am trying list comprehension.

I am trying to add words from a string into a list. But unable to do so. What am I doing wrong?

```
sentence = "there is nothing much in this"

wordList = sentence.split(" ") #normal in built function
print wordList

wordList = [ x for x in sentence if x!=" "] #using list comprehension
print wordList
```

Comment: `sentence.split(" ")` already gives you a list of words, so I'm not sure if there's any problem here.

Comment: i waanted to know about list compreshion. i tried to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
wordList = [ x for x in sentence if x!=" "] #using list comprehension
print wordList
```

will not work as you expect.

List Comphrehsnios in Python are basically a short-hand form of writing normal for-loops.

The above could be written as:

```
wordList = []
for x in sentence:
    if x != "":
        wordList.append(x)

print wordList
```

Do you see why this wouldn't work?

This would in effect iterate over all the characters in the string `sentence`.

Anything that you can do with a for-loop you can do with a list comprehension.

**Example:**

```
xs = []
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        xs.append(i)
```

is equivalent to:

```
xs = [i for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: I would assert that doing sentence.split() inside the list comprehension is completely redundant and therefore unnecessary - just the sentence.split() by itself will work

Comment: I agree with @Ajean -- My answer here is trying to illustrate to the OP **what** a List Comprehension really is and how to model and think about writing them.